# Как можно реализовать крон без падения?

Tags: python, cron

Есть вьюха на Flask, который проводит определенные манипуляции (делает выборку в БД, далее в зависимости от данных делает запросы на сторонние адреса) и есть крон задача, которая делает запрос 1 раз в день на эту вьюху.

Пока было малое количество пользователей, все отрабатывало исправно, но теперь количество пользователей стало больше и крон падает. Я так полагаю из-за длительного времени ожидания ответа, потому что если снова вручную запустить данный крон, то он отработает до конца.

Вопрос, можно ли как-то реализовать это одним обработчиком или придется просто разбивать на несколько кронов, например делить чтобы один крон отрабатывал только 1 пачку пользователей, затем если есть еще, то запускать 2 крон для 2ой пачки. Понимаю, что это не выход, но я пока вижу это так..

Может, мне посмотреть надо в дргую сторону?

Comment: что значит "крон падает"?

Comment: @strawdog, не приходит отчет по нему. В конце  вьюхи он на email должен отправить письмо с результатом, но оно не отправляется. Мне кажется, что из-за длительности обработчика - он просто отрубается. Например я когда я вручную его запускал (делал запрос через Postman) - он по 45 - 50 секунд работал и потом отправлял письмо. А автоматически видать он не может так долго ждать...

Comment: Ну как вариант это рефакторинг кода

1.Асинхронные запросы:переход к асинхронному выполнению запросов aiohttp

2.Оптимизация запросов к бд

3.Или посмотреть в сторону более производительного сервера